# custom config file defaults

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to create multi config files with defaults like config in my systemmanager (settings manager) i tried to create badwords file with defaults like config copy file from the plugin. But it did not work soo i guess that is impossible and i need to set the defaults i tried setting them in the systemmanager but it gives a error. Soo how do i set defaults like config have for my custom config? i hope you understand. The custom config file will be created with defaults if it does not exist like config. Here is my systemmanager:

```
package me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

public class SystemManager {

    private SystemManager() {}

    static SystemManager instance = new SystemManager();

    public static SystemManager getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    Plugin p;

    // Config
    FileConfiguration config;
    File cfile;

    // BadWords
    FileConfiguration badwordsdata;
    File badwordsfile;

    public void setup(Plugin p){
        // Config
        cfile = new File(p.getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
        config = p.getConfig();
        if(!cfile.exists()){
        config.options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().severe(ChatColor.RED + "UltimateCommandPack CONFIG does not exist! Creating new config!");
        }

        // BadWords
        badwordsfile = new File(p.getDataFolder(), "badwords.yml");
        badwordsdata = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(badwordsfile);
        if(!badwordsfile.exists()){
            badwordsdata.options().copyDefaults(true);
            savebadwordsdata();
            Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().severe(ChatColor.RED + "UltimateCommandPack BADWORDS does not exist! Creating new badwords!");
        }
    }

    // Config
    public FileConfiguration getConfig(){
        return config;
    }

    public void saveConfig(){
        try {
            config.save(cfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().severe(ChatColor.RED + "Could not save config.yml!");
        }
    }

    public void reloadConfig(){
        config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(cfile);
    }

    // BadWords
    public FileConfiguration getbadwordsdata(){
        return badwordsdata;
    }

    public void savebadwordsdata(){
        try {
            badwordsdata.save(badwordsfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().severe(ChatColor.RED + "Could not save badwords.yml!");
        }
    }

    public void reloadbadwordsdata(){
        badwordsdata = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(badwordsfile);
    }

}
```

Here is my project (plugin) full code if you need it:

```
package me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.EconomyResponse;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;
import org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredServiceProvider;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class System extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    SystemManager SysMng = SystemManager.getInstance();

    ArrayList<String> frozen = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Player> cooldown = new ArrayList<Player>();

    public static Economy econ = null;

    public void onEnable() {
        SysMng.setup(this);
        if (!setupEconomy()){
            getLogger().severe(String.format("[%s] - Disabled because vault was not found!", getDescription().getName()));
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been actived!");
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "ANNOUNCEMENT" + ChatColor.WHITE + "]" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Server creator: Herobrine112211!");
            }
        }, 100, 1400);
    }

    private boolean setupEconomy(){
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") == null){
            return false;
        }
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Economy> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Economy.class);
        if(rsp == null){
            return false;
        }
        econ = rsp.getProvider();
        return econ !=null;
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "All files have been saved!");
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been disabled! This will give big problems to server.");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent joinevent){
        Player getplayer = joinevent.getPlayer();
        getplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Hey " + getplayer.getName() + "! Welcome to the Ultimate Prison server!");
        // Spawning player in spawn location
        if(SysMng.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("spawn") == null){
            getplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Spawn is not set!. Report this problem to owner INSTANTLY!");
        }
        World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(SysMng.getConfig().getString("spawn.world"));
        double x = SysMng.getConfig().getDouble("spawn.x");
        double y = SysMng.getConfig().getDouble("spawn.y");
        double z = SysMng.getConfig().getDouble("spawn.z");
        getplayer.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
        if(getplayer.getName().equals("Herobrine112211")){
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.GOLD + "Server Creator Herobrine112211 has joined the game!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent moveevent) {
        Player getplayer = moveevent.getPlayer();
        if(frozen.contains(getplayer.getName())){
            moveevent.setTo(moveevent.getFrom());
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent chatevent){
        for (String word : chatevent.getMessage().split(" ")){
            if(SysMng.getbadwordsdata().getStringList("badwords").contains(word)){
                if (!chatevent.getPlayer().hasPermission("bypassbadwords")){
                chatevent.setCancelled(true);
                chatevent.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Dont use dirty (bad) words!");
             }
          }
        }
     }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent commandevent){
        String msg = commandevent.getMessage().toLowerCase();
        if(msg.startsWith("/op")){
            commandevent.setCancelled(true);
            commandevent.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Op command is only for owner.");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("contactowner")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("contactowner")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Console will never need owner support.");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Owner: Herobrine112211. Live chat skype: gangsteris33.");
                return true;
                }
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("reloadconfig")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("config.reload")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                SysMng.reloadConfig();
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config reloaded successfully.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("saveconfig")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("config.save")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                SysMng.saveConfig();
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config saved successfully.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakeop")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.op")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                    return true;
                }
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You are now op!");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakejoin")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.join")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a name!");
                    return true;
                }
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + args[0] + " joined the game.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("broadcast")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("broadcast")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please give a message to broadcast!");
                    return true;
                }
                StringBuilder strbl = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
                    strbl.append(args[i] + " ");
                }
                String broadcastas = strbl.toString();
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + broadcastas);
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("heal")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " healed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
                    return true;
                }
                    if(sender instanceof Player){
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                            player.setHealth(20);
                            player.setFireTicks(0);
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your health is now full!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " healed you!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
                    return true;
                    }
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kill")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("kill")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be killed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " killed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is killed!");
                    return true;
                    }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                            player.setHealth(0);
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You killed your self!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be killed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    target.setHealth(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " killed you!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is killed!");
                    return true;
                    }
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("feed")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " fed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.setFoodLevel(20);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your hunger is now full!");
                        return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                        return true;
                }
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                target.setFoodLevel(20);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " fed you!");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
                return true;
                }
        }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tpall")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("teleport")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Cannot teleport everyone to console!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                if(args.length == 0){
                    for(Player allplayers : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        World w = player.getLocation().getWorld();
                        double x = player.getLocation().getX();
                        double y = player.getLocation().getY();
                        double z = player.getLocation().getZ();
                        allplayers.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "All players teleported to you!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                for(Player allplayers : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if(target == null){
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                        return true;
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    World w = target.getLocation().getWorld();
                    double x = target.getLocation().getX();
                    double y = target.getLocation().getY();
                    double z = target.getLocation().getZ();
                    allplayers.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "All players teleported to player!");
                    return true;
                }
              }
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("setspawn")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot set spawn!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                SysMng.getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
                SysMng.getConfig().set("spawn.x", player.getLocation().getX());
                SysMng.getConfig().set("spawn.y", player.getLocation().getY());
                SysMng.getConfig().set("spawn.z", player.getLocation().getZ());
                SysMng.saveConfig();
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Spawn has been set!");
                return true;
                }
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("checkworld")){
                String worldName = SysMng.getConfig().getString("spawn.world");
                Bukkit.getLogger().info(worldName);
                return true;
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("spawn")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot teleport to spawn!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(getConfig().getConfigurationSection("spawn") == null){
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Spawn is not set!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(SysMng.getConfig().getString("spawn.world"));
                double x = SysMng.getConfig().getDouble("spawn.x");
                double y = SysMng.getConfig().getDouble("spawn.y");
                double z = SysMng.getConfig().getDouble("spawn.z");
                player.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                return true;
                }
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("freeze")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("freeze")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if(args.length == 0){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if(target == null){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(frozen.contains(target.getName())){
                    frozen.remove(target.getName());
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is now unfrozen!");
                    return true;
                }
                frozen.add(target.getName());
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is now frozen!");
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You have been frozen by administrator.");
                return true;
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kit")){
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot get kits!" + ChatColor.RED + "Kits:" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Starter");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!sender.hasPermission("kit")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    if(args.length == 0){
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Kits:" + ChatColor.GOLD + " Starter");
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("starter")){
                        if (!sender.hasPermission("kit.starter")){
                            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                            return true;
                        }

                        final Player player2 = (Player) sender;
                        if(cooldown.contains(player2)){
                            player2.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You cannot get this kit yet!. You can get kits every 24 hours.");
                            if (player2.hasPermission("kit.bypass")){
                                cooldown.remove(player2);
                                player2.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Admin access detected. Kit cooldown removed. Try again :)");
                                return true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                        if(sender instanceof Player){
                            Player player = (Player) sender;
                            PlayerInventory pinv = player.getInventory();
                            EconomyResponse withdraw = econ.withdrawPlayer(player.getName(), 10);
                            if(withdraw.transactionSuccess()){
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_PICKAXE, 1));
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD, 1));
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_AXE, 1));
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 20));
                                cooldown.add(player);
                                Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
                                    public void run(){
                                        cooldown.remove(player2);
                                    }
                                }, 1728000);
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You dont have required money ammount. Kit purchase failed!");
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Kit was not found. Do /kit for kits.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
   }
}
```

If you need something more just ask me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set the default values via `config.set()` if [`!file.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists())? For example:

```
//Get the file by name
File file = new File(p.getDataFolder(), "myCustomConfigFile.yml");
YamlConfiguration config = null;

//if the file doesn't exist...
if(!file.exists()){
    try{
       //create the new config file
       file.createNewFile();

       //get the custom config YamlConfiguration
       config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(badwordsfile);
       config.options().copyDefaults(true);

       //set default values in the config
       config.set("Bad Words", "Stupid, Shut Up, Poop");
       config.set("Punishment", "kick %player% don't say that"

       //save the YAMLConfiguration
       try{config.save(file);}
       catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
}
else{
    //otherwise, set the config to the current file
    config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
}
```

Comment: Yes that works but it write the defaults wrong it write them with ' these are breaking my code. Here how it should look: badwords: - apple - banana -test BUT its like that: badwords: ' - banana - apple - test - lol' how do i tell in code or something to dont use or remove '. This is how i did it: config.set("badwords", " - banana - apple - test - lol"); when that is solved my problem is fixed :).